# Wicket Link automatically Persist Object while AjaxLink do not

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wicket

I am using Wicket, JPA+Hibernate in a project

I have the persistence class like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
    "name"}) })
public class Document
implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8496087166198616020L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String state;
.....
 Geter && setters
```

Then

I have the dao implementation for crud operations

One method is

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void createDocument(Document aDocument)
{
        entityManager.persist(aDocument);
}
```

My Problem is, in the wicketPage, if I use a Wicket Link and it's onclick method doing the following

```
   document.setState("someState");
```

it updates the value with out calling the createDocument(document) specifically and the database is also up-to-date

But if I use AjaxLink and its onclick method

then, I have to manually update the object otherwise the value will not be updated in the database. My modification should be as follows:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void createDocument(Document aDocument)
{
        if(aDocument.getId()==0{
        entityManager.persist(aDocument);
        }
       else{
          entityManager.merge(aDocument);           
}
```

Then to save the changes in the Database, I have to first update the state and call `createDocument()` method.

```
         document.setState("someState");
         dao.createDocument(document);
```

Can anyone point out why this happens?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database session must be in AutoCommit mode. When you use the `Link` a "classic" `RequestCycle` is fired which certainly triggers your OpenSessionInView filter. This way, the `document` object that you update is still managed by the `Persistence Context`, thus, the underlying JPA implementation auto commits the change to the database.

When you use the `AjaxLink`, you're playing with a detached entity, JPA does not manage it and hence does not autocommit it to the database. When you call your `createDocument` method, you merge your entity with your `Persistence Context` and save it back.

If you do not want the autocommit to happen, you can set the FlushMode of your entityManager to `FlushMode.COMMIT`